# How to reference a databound control in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm creating `Canvas` objects programmatically in my codebehind and adding them to a `ListBox.Items`.  Now I want to create a `DataTemplate` for my `ListBox` that displays those `Canvas` objects with a border and highlights.

Prior to this I was using `Images` in my `ListBox` instead of `Canvases`, and was able to bind to a `BitmapImage` as the `Image.Source` property and this worked:

```
<ListBox Name="LayoutListBox">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="20,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="195" Height="195">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    // ...Some overlays and such
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But now that the `ListBox.Items` is using `Canvas` objects, I can't figure out how to reference them from the XAML.

```
<ListBox Name="LayoutListBox">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="20,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="195" Height="195">
                <Grid>
                    ----HOW DO I REFERENCE MY CANVAS FROM HERE?-----
                    // ...Some overlays and such
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Simply add the <`Canvas>` inside the `DataTemplate`?

Comment: @lll And then how does it get bound to the canvases in my `ListBox.Items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, `ContentPresenter` is what I needed.

```
<ListBox Name="LayoutListBox">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="20,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="195" Height="195">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                    // ...Some overlays and such
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I know this is a really old thread, but I am trying to accomplish exactly what you are. I don't understand how the ContentPresenter helps me reference my Canvas - any chance you could elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Do binding in your `Canvas` like this. e.g., You want to bind to the `Width` property of the `Canvas`

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Canvas Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox},Path=Items}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: But I don't want just the Width, or any subset of properties, I'm creating a complex Canvas object with lots of shapes and such on it programmatically, and I want the canvas itself, with any child elements I added to it in the codebehind, to be added to the grid.

Comment: More precise explanation would be recommended.

Comment: @DaxFohl Why don't you create the custom canvas that does the shape and code that it needs and set that as the data template. Also, define a custom `dependency property` so your custom logic that is required for your `Canvas` will depende on that dependency property where that dependency property is bound to the ListBox.Items

Comment: @michael Precise explanation of the question, the answer, or the comment?  (I have to admit it's a bit ironic to see such a vague demand for precision).